# How to set Amazon S3 bucket files permission to be only viewable?

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions

I am streaming videos from an Amazon S3 bucket using JWplayer to my website, but it has public access so everyone can view the videos and the problem is that anyone can also download the videos using that link.

How to give ACL permission to only view uploaded videos?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067904/prevent-direct-download-of-audio-files-from-amazon-s3

Comment: Ya that works but has one problem that it stop streaming videos from RTMP file link from cloudfront.net that I am using for JWplayer.